# How to save UIButton IBAction to UserDefaults with Codable in my static checklist, swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, codable, ibaction

How can I save the boolean value from when the user clicking on a checkbox (UIButton) in my checklist on a storyboard tableViewController?

have tried a lots of different tutorials but I don't get it because I have a boolean value and not a string ??? :S

The checklist app is complete and working but when checking boxes it does not get saved. when unchecking that should also get saved.

code for one of the 300 boxes I want to save:

```
    @IBAction func check1002Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {sender.isSelected = false }
    else {sender.isSelected = true }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

insert saving logic code after button tapped.

```
@IBAction func check1002Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
    }
    else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.isSelected, forKey: "check1002Selected")
}
```

and load button state before button appear.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "check1002Selected")
}
```

Comment: Check your parentheses

Comment: getting errors, any more code to add to this I'm a true beginner :)

Comment: thanx, still getting error for viewDidLoad, error: Cannot find 'button' in scope.

Comment: THANX again I got it to work now: connected the IBOutlet to the button where I got the "button" error. :D

Answer (score 0):

To any other beginners out there like me:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sender.isSelected, forKey: "check1002Selected")
```

the key can be any words you choose it seems to be created here.

```
button.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "check1002Selected")
```

where the "button" text is you write what you have named your @IBOutlet for the button you want to save. :D worked for me, happy happy beginner :D